# I am Not able to do authentication in bot using Azure bot service

Tags: botframework

I followed the link - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth

to use authentication in bot, but the article is not clear, at one place its mentioning to use echo bot, at the same time its asking to use code from github. After trying all the steps still it's not working

After trying all the steps in below link still it's not working
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth

There is a error in emulator can not post activity, unauthorised

Comment: "My bot isn't working, why?" is a lot to unpack. For using OAuth, you should be working with an oauth prompt, exemplified in in samples 18 and 24. Which sample are you running?

Comment: I am working with sample 18, Is there any article which provides hello world kind of steps to achieve authentication with active directory, as in link mentioned above its also mentioned to create bot where echo bot is selected then it's asked to use the sample on github

Comment: The only way it says to use an echo bot is if you switch away from that explicit doc on THAT page. Don't do that. Following each and every step in that doc is 'hello world' level of oauth  practice. I suggest you clone the samples repo, navigate to sample 18 and start from there.